# Craps simulator on python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

im doing a program for this casino game called craps. ive spent a lot of time doing it but i got stuck and i can't seem to find what the problem is. it doesnt loop it properly and it doesnt output properly.

here is my code so far

```
import random
from easygui import *
ans = boolbox("Would you like to play Craps?")
while ans == True:
    d1 = random.randint(1,6)
    d2 = random.randint(1,6)
    point = d1+d2
    counter = 1  
    string = ""
    if point == 7 or point == 11:  
        string += ("Roll #{}: [{}] [{}] ==> WIN!".format(counter,d1,d2))
    elif point == 2 or point == 3 or point == 12:
        string += ("Roll #{}: [{}] [{}] ==> LOSS!".format(counter,d1,d2)) 
    else:
        string += ("Roll #{}: [{}] [{}] ==> 'point' is {}".format(counter, d1,d2,point))
        num = point
        while num != 7:
            if counter == 1:
                string += ("Roll #{}: [{}] [{}] ==> keep going!".format(counter, d1,d2))
                counter +=1
                dice_1 = random.randint(1,6)
                dice_2 = random.randint(1,6)
                num = dice_1 + dice_2
                if num == point:
                    string += ("Roll #{}: [{}] [{}] ==> WIN!".format(counter, dice_1,dice_2))
                    counter +=1
                elif num == 7:
                    string+= ("Roll #{}: [{}] [{}] ==> LOSE!".format(counter, dice_1,dice_2))
                    counter+=1
                else:
                    string+= ("Roll #{}: [{}] [{}] ==> keep going!".format(counter,dice_1,dice_2))
```

Comment: its supposed to simulate the Craps casino game

Comment: Where do you think the problem is? What is it *actually doing* now?  See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i think the problem is after i change the value of num to point, the argument to the while loop isnt appropriate. right now its doing a bunch of weird stuff that it shouldnt be doing like infinite loops without actually outputting anything at one point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is a simplified version of what you are attempting to do.. and it works. In particular, I moved the craps core function

```
import random
from easygui import *

def rollDice(): # simulate a dice roll
    return random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)

def craps(): # roll dice and evaluate results
    firstRoll= rollDice()
    if firstRoll in (7,11):
        return 1 # initial winning condition
    if firstRoll in (2,3,12):
        return 0 #initial losing condition

    while True:
        newRoll = rollDice()
        if newRoll == firstRoll:
            return 1 #secondary winning condition
        if newRoll == 7:
            return 0 #secondary losing condition

ans = boolbox("Would you like to play Craps?")
while ans == True:
    result = craps()
    string = ""
    if( result == 1 ):
        string += ("WIN!")
    else:
        string += ("LOSS!")
    msgbox(string)
    ans = boolbox("Would you like to play Craps?")
```

EDIT: Strict assignment??? :)

```
import random
from easygui import *

ans = boolbox("Would you like to play Craps?")
while ans == True:
    looping = True
    firstRoll = random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)
    if firstRoll in (7,11):
        result = 1 # initial winning condition
        looping = False
    if firstRoll in (2,3,12):
        result = 0 #initial losing condition
        looping = False

    while looping:
        newRoll = random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)
        if newRoll == firstRoll:
            result = 1 #secondary winning condition
            looping = False
        if newRoll == 7:
            result = 0 #secondary losing condition
            looping = False

    string = ""
    if( result == 1 ):
        string += ("WIN!")
    else:
        string += ("LOSS!")
    msgbox(string)
    ans = boolbox("Would you like to play Craps?")
```

Comment: sorry but would it be possible to do with using only while/for loops, if/elif/else?

Comment: haha its not a strict assignment, more like we havent learnt those yet :P when im running the edited code it goes in an infinite loop?

Comment: @shahaadn: Nope, if you answer 'No' to the boolbox question, `ans` becomes `False`, the while-condition becomes `False` and thus the application exits. If my answer helped you to solve your issue, remember to accept my answer.